# Turn off all note sharing in Evernote

Tags: evernote

Suddenly hundreds of my notes are shared in Evernote. Could be a fault in some third party product. I have not programmed for Evernote before. Does anyone have a small piece of executable code for turning off note sharing for all my notes in all notebooks?

Answer (score 1):

You can [findNotes](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_findNotesMetadata) using the [search grammar](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/reference/NoteStore.html#Struct_NoteFilter) : "shareDate:*" and then use the [stopSharing](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_stopSharingNote) API to stop sharing the notes.

Comment: Thanks. Any chance of finding some executable code out there?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the GUID of each shared note and call `NoteStore.stopSharingNote(guid)`. Here's a quick-and-dirty Python solution that's untested, but should be pretty close to what you're looking for. Note that you'll need the Python SDK (installable via `pip`) to use this code.

```
import evernote.edam.notestore.ttypes as NoteStoreTypes
from evernote.api.client import EvernoteClient

auth_token = "" # set this to your dev token
useSandbox = True # change to False if you want to access your production account

client = EvernoteClient(token=auth_token, sandbox=True)

note_store = client.get_note_store()

offset = 0
chunkSize = 50
nFilter = NoteStoreTypes.NoteFilter()
nFilter.words = "sharedDate:*"
rSpec = NoteStoreTypes.NotesMetadataResultSpec()
while len(sharedGuids) % chunkSize == 0:
    nmd = note_store.findNotesMetaData(nFilter, offset, chunkSize, rSpec)
    for n in nmd.notes:
        note_store.stopSharingNote(n.guid)
    offset += chunkSize
```

If you have any trouble with this, head over to our [support page](http://dev.evernote.com/support) and get in touch and we'll help you out.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much! This is pretty close to what I wanted. I also see that there is a SDK for Ruby, which I allready have installed. So I now have a couple of routes to follow. Awsome!